# Dynamically load the image from database on the css background

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I am using JSP pages for my project. I need to upload the background-image from my database.

If I am using the image tag the it is possible using following sytntax:-

```
<img src="${testimonial.image }"height="50px" width="50px"></img>
```

now I have to apply the background-image property in div.

```
div{
    background: url('/resources/images/logo.png') no-repeat top left;  
}
```

Now please tell me how to set variable in css background-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, what about using this:

```
<div id="variable_background" style="background-image: url(${image_path})"></div>
```

If you want to change it dynamically, you can use:

```
var newImagePath = 'path/to/your/image.png';
document.getElementById('variable_background').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + newImagePath + "')";
```